# Кириллица в postToChat() из библиотеки mcpi.minecraft в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю питон по книге Крэйга Ричардсона "Программируем с Minecraft".
Там представлена следующая программа:

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
mc = Minecraft.create()
mc.postToChat("Привет, мир Minecraft!")
```

В теории она должна выводить текст в чат игры, у меня же она работает только с английскими символами в кавычках, а при использовании кириллицы выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mrSuslik/Documents/Minecraft Python/chat/hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    mc.postToChat("Привет, мир Minecraft!")
  File "C:\Users\mrSuslik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mcpi\minecraft.py", line 163, in postToChat
    self.conn.send(b"chat.post", msg)
  File "C:\Users\mrSuslik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mcpi\connection.py", line 39, in send
    s = b"".join([f, b"(", flatten_parameters_to_bytestring(data), b")", b"\n"])
  File "C:\Users\mrSuslik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mcpi\util.py", line 10, in flatten_parameters_to_bytestring
    return b",".join(map(_misc_to_bytes, flatten(l)))
  File "C:\Users\mrSuslik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mcpi\util.py", line 18, in _misc_to_bytes
    return str(m).encode("cp437")
  File "C:\Users\mrSuslik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. В интернете статей на эту тему не нашел, поэтому прошу помощи здесь.

Надеюсь, вы сможете помочь.

Comment: В книге написано скачать и установить `Minecraft Tools.zip` по ссылке https://mif.to/minecraft — вы сделали это?

Comment: Да, всё скачал и сделал, как написано в инструкции.

Comment: И тем не менее вы почему-то используете неправильную версию mcpi. Вы делали что-то, что не было написано в книге?

Comment: Только что обновил библиотеку mcpi, и postToChat() заработала. Но теперь промбемы с кодировкой, т.к. в чат вместо русских букв выводятся неизвестные символы.

Comment: Ваш файл с кодом сохранён точно в кодировке utf-8?

Comment: Да. На всякий случай пересохранил файл в utf8, но ничего не изменилось. Пишу и запускаю программу в IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже занимаюсь по этой книге, а также по [курсам школы Пиксель](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCenaLQKkLwAUmxmwzV8fJjg/videos)

Они взяли эту книгу за основу и придумали более продвинутые примеры.
Я настроил кириллицу в чате Майнкрафта, применив шаги:

1. Обновил библиотеку mcpi по сравнению с версией, приложенной к книге, на более новую версию:

   ```
   $ pip install mcpi
   ```
2. В start.bat добавил `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, после чего он принял вид:

   ```
   @echo off
   java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar spigot.jar
   pause
   ```

Теперь

```
mc.postToChat('Тест кириллицы')
```

печатает в чат кириллицу.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте добавить в начале файла

```
# coding: utf8    
import sys    
reload(sys)    
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: Если вы внимательно изучите текст ошибки и заглянете в исходники mcpi, то поймёте, что это не поможет.

Comment: Более того, ваш код выдаст ошибку `NameError: name 'reload' is not defined`

Comment: Так и есть, я уже пробовал это, когда искал решение в интернете.

Answer (score 0):

Быстрое, но не красивое решение. Идете в:

```
%user%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\mcpi\
```

если Python инсталлирован для конкретного пользователя (у меня так),
ну или где у вас находятся библиотеки Python, можете поискать папку 'mcpi'
и правите файл util.py - меняете самую последнюю строчку:

```
return str(m).encode("cp437")
```

на:

```
return str(m).encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ксожалению, юникод вы использовать не сможете. там используется CP437 https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP437

смотрите:
https://github.com/martinohanlon/mcpi/blob/master/mcpi/connection.py

```
def send(self, f, *data):
    """
    Sends data. Note that a trailing newline '\n' is added here
    The protocol uses CP437 encoding - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437
    which is mildly distressing as it can't encode all of Unicode.
    """
    s = b"".join([f, b"(", flatten_parameters_to_bytestring(data), b")", b"\n"])
    self._send(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ**
Ошибка во второй строке: должно быть написано minecraft.Minecraft.create()

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! вы уверены в правильности такого совета? пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]